# Combinatorics- Calculating Grundy Value

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck in this problem and cannot really understand my textbook.

Two players take turns to play the following game. A basket contains 5 apples, 6 oranges, and 9 pears. At each turn the players are allowed to take 1, 2 or 3 fruits of same kind. The winner takes the last fruit.

(a) Find the value of the Grundy function at the initial position.
(b) What is a first winning move?

What I have been trying,

```
                                   Binary          Grundy Value
A: | | | | |                5       0101               1 
O: | | | | | |              6       0110               2
P: | | | | | | | | |        9     + 1001             + 1
                                    1010 = 10          2
```

I calculated Grundy Value as 2(which I used XOR). So is 2 correct for problem (a)?
For problem(b), since Grundy Value is 2, first winning move is take 2 from any fruits. (?)

Comment: Looks right.  You're using the fact that the nim-value of each component (fruit type) is the number of that type of fruit modulo 4.  And in general a winning move is one that leaves your opponent with nim-value 0... which in this case does mean taking 2 of any kind of fruit.

Comment: @mjqxxxx I didn't think that it is modulo 4. I counted one by one. But now it kinda makes sense why it uses modulo 4, because the players can take up to 3 fruits.